# Group data and jump to next case

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a data frame (df1t) like this:

```
userid | interaction | goal
0001   | Access1     |  0
0001   | Access2     |  1
0001   | Access3     |  0
0002   | Access1     |  1
0003   | Access2     |  0
```

For grouping this data I'm using:

```
library(dplyr)
usrlvl <- df1t %>% 
group_by(userid) %>% 
summarise(path = paste(interaction, collapse = " > "),
      goal = sum(goal)
)
```

The result is something like this

```
userid | path                        | goal
0001   | Access1 > Access2 > Access3 |  1
0002   | Access1                     |  1
0003   | Access2                     |  0
```

But I have some problem with this result. My path should stop in the goal and ignore the others interactions. The result have to seems like this:

```
userid | path               | goal
0001   | Access1 > Access2  |  1
0002   | Access1            |  1
0003   | Access2            |  0
```

Someone had a problem like this?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if the goal changes from 0 to 1 then the path stops at the row where goal = 1?

Comment: Yes. The path stops when condition where goal = 1.

Answer (score 1):

One way with `dplyr`

```
usrlvl <- df1t %>% 
  group_by(userid) %>% 
  filter(!(goal==0 & cumsum(goal)==1))%>%
  summarise(path = paste(interaction, collapse = " > "),
            goal = sum(goal))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  userid              path  goal
   <dbl>             <chr> <dbl>
1      1 access1 > access2     1
2      2           access1     1
3      3           access2     0
```

Comment: I think this will fail if there is more than one interaction after the initial goal state is reached. That is, if you added "access 4" to userid 001, that would be included in your paste output.

Comment: Modified, hopefully it's more robust now?

Comment: Very slick approach to the filtering. There is ambiguity in the question, leading to these issues. That should work, unless multiple goal states can be reached and OP wants to record that in the sum. I assumed in mine that ze only wanted the path to the first one, but still wanted the total count of goals reached. However, I have no idea if that is a valid assumption or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `which.max` to stop at the last goal before goal changes from one to zero

```
usrlvl <- df1t %>% 
  group_by(userid) %>% 
  summarise(path = paste(interaction[1:which.max(goal)], collapse = " > "),
            goal = sum(goal)
  )
#A tibble: 3 × 3
#  userid              path  goal
#   <int>             <chr> <int>
#1      1 Access1 > Access2     1
#2      2           Access1     1
#3      3           Access2     0
```

Comment: I think that this fails if there is more than one step without reaching a goal. E.g., if you add "Access3" for userid 3 with goal still at 0

Comment: @MarkPeterson Nothing in OP to say whether your suggested case can occur or what to do if it does. OP needs to clarify the desired behaviour. This method fits the example as given. We cant really 2nd guess what OP wants to happen in situations they don't even describe

Comment: completely fair point @dww , and this is on OP. I have no idea if my assumptions are correct about desired behavior. I thought this was a really great approach, and was only trying to explain why I still felt the need to expand on it. Sorry for my lack of clarity in my comment as well.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to write a function that captures a goal state, and writes out the path to that state. Makes the code a little cleaner, especially if you need to do this often (or with different types of criteria).

First, define the function:

```
untilGoal <- function(x, goal){
  if(sum(goal) >= 1){
    paste(x[1:(which(goal)[1])], collapse = " > ")
  } else
    paste(x, collapse = " > ")
}
```

Which expects two vectors, one to paste and one that is a logical (this is what allows the flexibility). Then, use that function in your `summarise` call:

```
df %>%
  group_by(userid) %>%
  summarise(path = untilGoal(interaction, goal == 1)
            , goal = sum(goal))
```

gives:

```
  userid              path  goal
1      1 Access1 > Access2     1
2      2           Access1     1
3      3           Access2     0
```